# Support for JSON in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g

Does Oracle 11g support JSON? I mean stuff like manipulating JSON objects in PL/SQL Queries. I know Oralcle 12c has the support for these things but it seems 11g does not.

My main concern is whether it is possible to handle JSON objects returned from RESTfull API calls (using `UTL_HTTP` package) in PL/SQL code.

This is how I call RESTfull APIs:

```
req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('https://xxxx/api/job/all', 'GET', 'HTTP/1.1');

  UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(req, 'apikey','xxxxx');
  resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
```

Then need to somehow save retruned JSON data in tables. My Oracle envirment is: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, JSON support was introduced in Oracle database 12c release 2 (12.1.0.2)

Regards

Comment: @Charang  you can store JSON messages as CLOB/BLOB/VARCHAR2 and then write your own PL/SQL API or use a third party API to work with them. You may use this API: https://github.com/pljson/pljson (or other similar to this one). Give it a try.

Answer (score 10):

If you install the latest [APEX 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html) which was released on April 15. You get access to a great API to work with JSON

I'm using it on 11.2 and have been able to crunch every single json, from simple to very complex objects with multiple arrays and 4/5 levels.  [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635)

If you do not want to use APEX.  Simply install the runtime environment to get access to the API.